# Finding in which class or subclass methods were defined

Tags: python, class, methods, subclass, inspect

After evaluating the following code:

```
class A():
  def method1():
    pass
  def method2():
    pass

class B(A):
  def method3():
    pass
  def method4():
    pass

class C(B):
  def method1(): # notice the overriding of A.method1
    pass
  def method5():
    pass

myC = C()
import inspect
# Find all methods
print [attr for attr in inspect.getmembers(myC) if callable(attr[1])]
```

> [('method1', bound method C.method1 of <**builtin**.C instance at 0x079EA0D0>),
>   ('method2', bound method C.method2 of <**builtin**.C instance at 0x079EA0D0>), ('method3', bound method C.method3 of <**builtin**.C instance at 0x079EA0D0>), ('method4', bound method C.method4 of <**builtin**.C instance at 0x079EA0D0), ('method5', builtin.C instance at 0x079EA0D0>)]

How to retrieve the origin of the methods ?

- method1 and method5  come directly from class C definition
- method3 and method4 come from subclass B of class C
- method2 comes from subclass A of subclass B of class C.

For those who like to known the final goal, I want to display help for the methods directly defined in class C, not in subclasses.

Comment: This can do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/9437273/1587534 you use super() to get the parent, you compare method names, done

Comment: So your real question is *"how can I get the methods defined directly in `C`"*? That's actually *easier* than the question you've written; just look in `C.__dict__`.

Comment: Yes and no. In my software, the user selects up to which hierarchical depth he wants help for the object methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the attribute is present in `myC`'s class `__dict__`:

```
for attr in filter(lambda m: callable(m[1]), inspect.getmembers(myC)):
    if attr[0] in myC.__class__.__dict__:
        # print help
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
method1 and method5 come directly from class C definition
method3 and method4 come from subclass B of class C
method2 comes from subclass A of subclass B of class C.
"""
import inspect
class A():
  def method1():
    pass
  def method2():
    pass

class D():
  def method8():
    pass
  def method9():
    pass

class B(A, D):
  def method3():
    pass
  def method4():
    pass

class C(B):
  def method1(): # notice the overriding of A.method1
    pass
  def method5():
    pass

# my solution is a recursive method for classes/methods(nested) 
def bases(cls):
  for _bases in cls.__bases__:
    print cls, ">", _bases
    if inspect.isclass(_bases):
      print ">", _bases, [method for method in dir(_bases) if callable(getattr(_bases, method))]
      bases(_bases)

bases(C)


__builtin__.C > __builtin__.B
> __builtin__.B ['method1', 'method2', 'method3', 'method4', 'method8', 'method9']
__builtin__.B > __builtin__.A
> __builtin__.A ['method1', 'method2']
__builtin__.B > __builtin__.D
> __builtin__.D ['method8', 'method9']
```

Comment: This solution is the most powerful to locate precisely the method definition